# Ways to create object of ResponseEntity class in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I am new to spring boot and I am trying to create handler methods to create REST API in spring boot. To handle request ***localhost:8080/stack*** I created below handler method in which I used constructor of ResponseEntity to create its object and pass it in return statement.

```java
 @GetMapping("/stack")
    public ResponseEntity<String> stack(){
        System.out.println("I am stack method");
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Body",HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

But I can also do it by using the below method

```java
 @GetMapping("/stack")
    public ResponseEntity<String> stack(){
        System.out.println("I am stack method");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body("Body");
    }
```

I don't know which is the best way to create and return an object of ResponseEntity in the handler method using constructors or using build method() and why? Somebody please help here. Which is the most preferred way in the production?

Comment: It's a matter of taste :)

Comment: Its a matter of tase, as a matter of fact you could even do `ResponseEntitiy.ok("Body");` or `ResponseBody.ok().body("Body");` which would be clearer and more concise.

Comment: Note that if you _do_ use `status` (which is necessary for less common ones like 429), it is a good idea to statically import the enum values, because the code is more readable.

Comment: In this case I would just return a String like public String stack(). I only ever define ResponseEntity return object when I need to add things to it in that method. All 3 ways are going to give you the same results though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same as even 2nd approach returns a new object of ResponseEntity class. If you check the implementation of the *body* method as below:-

```
@Override
    public <T> ResponseEntity<T> body(@Nullable T body) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(body, this.headers, this.statusCode);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ResponseEntity is meant to represent the entire HTTP response. You can control anything that goes into it: status code, headers, and body.

@ResponseBody is a marker for the HTTP response body and @ResponseStatus declares the status code of the HTTP response.

@ResponseStatus isn't very flexible, ResponseEntity lets you do more.

Answer (score 0):

In that case best way is to return string ("Body") from restcontroller method, it'll be wrapped in responseentity with response status 200 OK automatically

Comment: That actually depends on the type of controller.

Comment: Not if you annotate your method with @ResponseBody

Comment: Correct, but that wasn't part of your answer. Your answer assumed `@RestController`.

Comment: Either restcontoller or responsebody will do the work, I dont know whats an issue here

Comment: Your initial answer mentioned controller **not** restcontoller (which you modified as I can see).